# Hiding the title of the bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I'd like to get rid of the bibliography heading:
[image]

Please note that I'm using the `thebibliography` environment.

Comment: Honestly, I do net really understand your question. My guess is GoogleTranslate or similar. Could you, even with insufficient english, try to rephrase your problem?

Comment: Regis, the wording is really confusing. It would be good if you tried to explain better what you want, perhaps with the help of google translate or similar.

Comment: Regis, my guess is that you are trying to remove the bibliography heading. Maybe you could also provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). OFF: Nice to see another brazilian around. `=)`

Comment: Regis, I speak Portuguese. If you explain what you need in a comment I can translate it for you.

Comment: @Paulo Cereda: and another brazilian :)

Comment: @Regis What package are you using to setup the bibliography?

Comment: @Vivi: Oh hello! `=P`

Comment: ola pessoal, desculpe-me se não consegui me expressar em inglês, eu só quero tirar o título 'referencia' da bibliografia. só isso.

Comment: I would guess locally redefining `\section` to simply remove it's argument should do it.

Comment: I use \begin{thebibliography}

Comment: Eu não consegui ainda. Eu queria uma coisa simples com \begin{thebibliography}

Comment: @Regis: Eu tomei a liberdade de traduzir seu comentário para o Inglês e alterei o texto da sua questão para tentar melhorar a legibilidade. Se precisar editá-lo novamente, fique à vontade. Qualquer coisa, @Vivi e eu podemos te auxiliar.

Comment: ok, fico no aguardo. Obrigado.

Comment: @Regis da Silva : meu email esta no meu perfil. A resposta abaixo nao resolve seu problema? Se nao resolve, explica pq nao e o que quer.

Comment: @Vivi, seu email não aparece no seu perfil, mas o meu aparece, será que vc pode me enviar um email por favor? grato!

Comment: @Regis what document class are you using? Is the image from your document?

Comment: i use article...

Comment: @Regis so Martin's solution should work well for you.

Comment: Yes, @Martin solved my problem. Thank you all.

Comment: Duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33316/bibtex-with-no-references-title, but the accepted answer here is better IMO as it does not require `\vspace`.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

The `thebibliography` environment uses `\section*{\refname}` (`article` class and similar classes) or `\chapter*{\bibname}` (`book` and `report` and similar classes) internally. Redefining that macro locally to take and discard two arguments (one for `*`, one for the actual argument) will remove the headline.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\renewcommand{\section}[2]{}%
%\renewcommand{\chapter}[2]{}% for other classes
\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem{ano05}
    A. Nonymous et al.\ 2005
\bibitem{oe04}
    A.N. Other \& S.O.M. Ebody 2004
\end{thebibliography}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

This also works for BibTeX's `\bibliography{..}` because it uses `thebibliography` internally. For this use:

```
\begingroup
\renewcommand{\section}[2]{}%
%\renewcommand{\chapter}[2]{}% for other classes
\bibliography{mybibfile}
\endgroup
```

Comment: Building on @Martin's answer, if you want to use a subsection or other header instead change the line `\renewcommand{\section}[2]{}%` to `\renewcommand{\section}[2]{\subsection#1{#2}}%` or equivalent.

Comment: This only hides section in text, but not in the table of contents ...

Comment: Hmm, in my tests with `book`, I get with `\traceon`: `\thebibliography #1->\chapter *{\bibname }\@mkboth {\MakeUppercase \bibname }{\
MakeUppercase \bibname }...` ; and so even if I do `\renewcommand{\chapter}[2]{}`, some of the "Bibliography" title still leaks (via \MakeUppercase, apparently)? I guess in such a case, it only remains to set `\bibname` to empty, as suggested below...

Comment: This solution just removes all section titles after the `\renewcommand`.  What if you have an appendix after the bibliography?

Comment: [This alternative answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132647/6376) to an unofficial duplicate does want I want.

Comment: @martin-scharrer How can I redefine the \section macro to be its original definition?  My document class is "article".  The bibliography is not the last section so I need to restore the old definition afterwards.

Comment: @Seeda: If the change is wrapped in `\begingroup` .. `\endgroup` the old definition will be restored afterwards automatically.

Comment: It is `\renewcommand{\section}[1]{}` in my case.

Answer (score 63):

If you use biblatex you can use the bibliography heading `none` which was added in version 1.5 (see [the manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), section 3.5.7). I've got an earlier version so I can't try it but I think the following is an example of this option in use:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{database.bib}
@book{texbook,
    author  = {Donald E. Knuth},
    title   = {The {{\TeX}book}},
    publisher   = {Addison-Wesley},
    date    = {1984}
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\bibliography{database.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{texbook}

\printbibliography[heading=none]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Although this a good answer for the general case, Regis is just using `\begin{thebibliography}` ... `\end{thebibliography}` so this won't help, I don't think.

Comment: @Alan: Yes, but it is good to have also an BibLaTeX solution around. Other people will have the same needs but use it instead.

Comment: Other people such as myself... This was the first place that actually had the answer for biblatex. It's in the manual, but the manual is too long to read.

Answer (score 11):

Redefine the `\bibsection`-command. You want it empty, so do:

`\renewcommand{\bibsection}{}`

(Credits to http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4089, where I found the solution which worked for me.)

Comment: As they say in the link, this works only if \bibsection is defined and used somewhere, e.g. with natbib.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute your code with something like that.

```
\bibliographystyle{abntex2-alf}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{}
\bibliography{references.bib}
```

This worked using `abntex2` style.

Comment: Just redefining `\bibname` to be empty will likely cause incorrect spacing (from the "empty" section) at the start of the bibliography.