# Bibtex with no references title

Tags: sectioning, bibliographies

I am working on writing a scientific poster in LaTeX, and I want to include a few references for my work.  Because this is a poster, I have my own customized headers for different sections, and don't want my related works to have a separate title.  Essentially I have something like this:

```
\begin{textblock}{5.5}(19.5,11)
\CHead{Related Work} %a newcommand header I wrote
\bibliographystyle{acm}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{textblock}
```

And it comes out with a header called "Related Work" like I want, but it also under that says "References", which I don't want.

I found a few websites that said that I could override this with something like

```
\renewcommand\refname{}
```

But all this does is take the word "References" out, but the space allotted for the title is still there.  Is there a way to completely eliminate the title and any space it may take up?

Comment: Good answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22654/7825

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What wound up working best for me was to use `\renewcommand\refname{}` and then use negative vspace like so:

```
\begin{textblock}{5.5}(19.5,11)
\CHead{Related Work} %a newcommand header I wrote
\vspace*{-4cm}
\bibliographystyle{acm}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{textblock}
```

Answer (score 10):

I did a

```
\renewcommand\refname{\vskip -1cm}
\section{References}
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{report}
```

Answer (score 5):

`\renewcommand{\refname}{}` just redefines the `\refname` (that is, the title of your related work section) to be blank.  I believe you want to redefine the title of your related work section to be `\CHead{Related Work}`.

So, I would try writing `\renewcommand{\refname}{\CHead{Related Work}}` instead of manually inserting `\CHead{Related Work}` before the bibliography.

Comment: Good suggestion, but it formats things differently because I guess it wants to conform to what it thinks the bibliography header should look like.

Comment: In what way(s) does the format not match what you want?  It does get printed larger because BibTeX treats it as a section heading, but there are still things you can do to manipulate its appearance.  For instance, I tested this solution by putting `\renewcommand{\refname}{\center This is {\small my} {\em custom} name}` into the heading of one of my LaTeX documents, and it did appear centered with small "my" and italicized "custom", as expected.  So, you still may be able to tweak the appearance of the custom heading, depending on what exactly is not right about it.

Answer (score 0):

I used 
`\fancyhead{}`  before I set my custom fancyheader options and my problem was solved. I'm not sure if it will remove the space allotted for the header.