# Remove bibliography title in moderncv with multibib

Tags: sectioning, bibliographies, moderncv, subdividing, multibib

I want to have multiple bibliographies within my CV (moderncv class) so I've been using `multibib`.  The trouble is, `multibib` automatically places a bibliography title above each bibliography, which I do not always want.

At the beginning of my document I have:

```
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{Jn,Cp,Pt}{{Journal Articles},{Conference Proceedings},{Patents}}
```

Then, when I have

```
\section{Patents}
\nocitePt{nM09}
\bibliographystylePt{bibstyle}
\bibliographyPt{LinkedBib_2011-09-28}
```

I end up with [patents twice](http://postimage.org/image/odr48bfef/), one from the section heading, and one from the bibliography title.  I want to keep the section heading, so the bibliography title needs to go.

I've tried leaving the bibliography title out of the `\newcites` command, like this

```
\newcites{Jn,Cp,Pt}{{Journal Articles},{Conference Proceedings},{}}
```

But this just results in a [big space](http://postimage.org/image/op8kl2vuf/) between the section title and the first bibliography item.

I also tried

```
\section{Patents}
\begingroup
\renewcommand{\section}[2]{}%
\nocitePt{nM09}
\bibliographystylePt{bibstyle}
\bibliographyPt{LinkedBib_2011-09-28}
\endgroup
```

which was suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22645/hiding-the-title-of-the-bibliography), but I still ended up with patents twice.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 15):

`moderncv` adjusts the bibliography environment to issue `\subsection` when `multibib` is loaded.

You should be able to correct this by saying

```
\renewcommand*{\bibliographyhead}[1]{}
```

after `\begin{document}`

Comment: That did it!  Thanks.  I guess you have some experience with the moderncv package.

Comment: @Ben Never used. :) But the issue was very clear when looking inside the class file.