# Omit heading in biblatex with printbibliography

Tags: biblatex, sectioning

Is it possible to omit the heading when I use the `\printbibliography` command?

I want to print two different bibliographies one after the other and need to add some text between the second heading and the bibitems.

> ## 1 References
>
> bibitem1
>
> bibitem2
>
> ## 2 Sources
>
> Some text here but just a little bit
>
> bibitem1
>
> bibitem2

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Yes, if you just want to get rid of the headings, just use `\printbibliography[heading=none]`. You have other options to customize the headings through `\defbibheading` (see section 3.6.7 of the `biblatex` manual). There are several predefined headings which you can choose by specifying the option `[heading=]` to `\printbibliography`, `none` is one of these.

Note that if you want to add some text between the heading and the list of references, you also have the option `prenote` which you can supply to `\printbibliography`.

Here is an example using `prenote` and `title` to change the title of the second reference list.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{A2012,
author = {Author, A},
title = {An interesting paper},
journal = {Journal},
year = {2012},
volume = {2},
pages = {70--76},
}
@article{B2012,
author = {Buthor, B},
title = {An also interesting paper},
journal = {Journal},
year = {2012},
volume = {2},
pages = {77--79},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1] \cite{A2012}

\printbibliography


\newrefsection
\lipsum[2] \cite{B2012}

\defbibnote{note}{Here are some additional references for further reading}

\printbibliography[title={Sources},prenote=note]

\end{document}
```

And the output:

[image]

Comment: The documentation is definitely too big! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: How about effecting a \thispagestyle{myheadings} command on the \printbibliography command, how can I do that? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

See the answer (with example) given by Martin Scharrer:

The `thebibliography` environment uses `\section*{\refname} (article` class and similar classes) or `\chapter*{\bibname}` (book and report and similar classes) internally. Redefining that macro locally to take and discard two arguments (one for *, one for the actual argument) will remove the headline. Example...

[Hiding the title of the bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22645/hiding-the-title-of-the-bibliography)