# Undefined control sequence \printbibliography

Tags: bibliographies, errors

Could anybody give me some help on this problem I've come over?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
    \bibliographystyle{ormsv080}
    \bibliography{MST_TBS}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

when compiling, I got the error:

```
! undefined control sequence
1.13 \printbibliography
```

Comment: `natbib` doesn't use/provide `\printbibliography`: the latter is part of `biblatex`, an alternative approach to `natbib`.

Comment: ... so you don't want to have both `\bibliography{..}` and `\printbibliography`. Just remove the latter.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/) gets messed up by the inclusion of both `biblatex` & `bibtex` based commands, as @JosephWright points out. Also, `\usepackage[style=<somebiblatexstyle>,<other options>]{biblatex}`, `\addbibresource[<options for bib resources>]{<mybibfile>.bib}% Syntax for version >= 1.2` are also missing from your MWE preamble. To get things working properly with `biblatex`, follow the following excellent links: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/78565 & https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Bibliography_management_with_biblatex .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined control sequence in \printbibliography (biblatex)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148314/undefined-control-sequence-in-printbibliography-biblatex)

Comment: @Amar No, that is not a duplicate.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Well, if you look at @andrew-swann 's comment just under that question, he points out that the main problem in that code was the confusion between `\addbibresource` & `\bibliography`, which solves the OP's main problem apart from the encoding-based errors in the `.bib` file and that to me was a secondary issue in his post. OP's own answer given below is a proof of that. So, I still think that these two posts should be treated as duplicates, albeit partial duplicates of each other. Thanks for your reply though. Appreciated.

Comment: @Amar While the use of `\bibliography` with `biblatex` is deprecated, and `\addbibresource` is recommended, the former *does not produce any errors*, so I doubt that was actually the main problem -- the undefined control sequence reported looks like it is encoding related. The problem here is that `\printbibliography` is used without `biblatex` present at all, and I fail to see how that is a duplicate.  (But we're perhaps digressing a bit, you can ping me in chat if you want to continue the discussion.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Nope! You make a valid point! Thank you. ... Can't take back my flag now can I? :)

Answer (score 5):

I assume the unformatted bibliographic entries are contained in the file `MST_TBS.bib`. Depending on whether you want to create the bibliography with either `natbib` (and BibTeX) or `biblatex` (and `biber`), you should use one of the following templates.

1. `natbib` and BibTeX

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{natbib}
   \bibliographystyle{ormsv080}
   \begin{document}
       ....
       \bibliography{MST_TBS} % note: no ".bib" extension
   \end{document}
   ```

   Assuming the main tex file is called `main.tex`, the compilation sequence is

   ```
   latex main
   bibtex main
   latex main
   latex main
   ```
2. `biblatex` and `biber`

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage[<various options that replicate the settings of 
                the "ormsv080" bibliography style>]{biblatex}
   \addbibresource{MST_TBS.bib} % note the ".bib" extension
   \begin{document}
       ....
       \printbibliography
   \end{document}
   ```

   Now, the compilation sequence is

   ```
   latex main
   biber main
   latex main
   ```

Comment: Isn't there a typo at `\addbibresource{{MST_TBS.bib}` (no closing `}`)?

Comment: @pushpen.paul - Thanks.  Yup, that was a typo. :-(

Answer (score 1):

This error can also occur if used with a document class (such as `letter`) that doesn't have section commands defined, leading to an error like this:

```
Undefined control sequence.
\\blx@head@bibliography [#1]->\section 
    *{#1}\@mkboth {\abx@MakeMarkcase {#1}...
```

This is because Biblatex depends on `\section` commands being available to print the "References" heading. Either [define](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/400123/188504) `\section` manually or just [omit the heading](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102693/188504) from the bibliography altogether, like this:

```
\printbibliography[heading=none]
```