# PdfLatex build error due to the ".bib" file compilation error

Tags: bibliographies, pdftex, texstudio

I am writing in TexStudio and it builds *PdfLatex* if I don't include the *printbibliography* command. But when I include it, it shows *printbibliography* as an unrecognized command and I don't get *Bibliography* page into my pdf output.

I have also tried compiling the *.bib* file (as it was working few days ago) with just one citation, before I actually use the mentioned citation into my *.tex* file but it does not compile (see the image of an error). I think as I can't compile  *.bib* file, I'm not getting *bibliography* into the pdf  output. Any suggestion? [image: error while compiling the .bib file]

```
\usepackage[ backend=biber, 
style=numeric,
sortlocale=de_DE, 
natbib=true, 
url=true, 
doi=true, 
eprint=false
]  {biblatex} 
\addbibresource{literatur.bib}
% Biblatex Kompatibilität 
\usepackage{csquotes} 

\begin{document}
\include{inhalt/01-Introduction} 
\include{inhalt/02-CHP_systems} 

\listoftables 
\printbibliography 

\begin{appendix} 
\include{Appendix} 
\end{appendix}     
\end{document}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  it's not clear whether you are using bibtex or biblatex.  only biblatex supports the `\printbibliography` command.  the information associated with this question might help: [Undefined control sequence `\printbibliography`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/331633/579).

Comment: Try removing the `\printbibliography` instruction first. It's almost certainly not needed. You do have a `\bibliography{<name of bib file>}` instruction somewhere in the document, likely at the very end, right?

Comment: A minimal working example would answer both of the previous questions, and maybe others as well...

Comment: I'm using _biblatex_.  and I have also tried with [\bibliography{<name of bib file>}] but this does not work as well.  I have included the working code into my main post. Please see @Elad Den

Comment: Can you test if the following works: 1) Go to the "abschlussarbeit.tex" document 2) `tools->commands->pdflatex`, then from the same menu `biber`, two times `pdflatex` and then `tools->view`.

Comment: and try with `\bibliography{literatur}` instead of `\addbibresource`

Comment: Thanks. It works and I got the bibliography page @samcarter But it's now giving another error _"Misplaced alignment tab character &. \begin"_ at  _\begin {appendix}_ line.

Comment: If this error was not there prior to adding the bibliography, there is probably a `&` somewhere in the .bib which should be a `\&`. BUt can also be another error somewhere.

Comment: Furthermore there is no environment `{appendix}`! It is a macro and should be `\appendix`.

Comment: Yes, there was _&_ without _\_ in _.bib_ file which I've corrected and everything works fine now. Thank, I appereciate your time. @samcarter

Comment: @ArslanYousaf You're welcome!

Comment: @ArslanYousaf To make compiling easier, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154754/36296