# How do I change "References" title in APA6?

Tags: bibliographies, naming, apa6

I've a document that I have to write in spanish, therefore I've to change the title of "References" section to "Referencias I've used:

```
\renewcommand{\refname}{Referencias}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Referencias}
\renewcommand{\mspart}{Referencias}
```

But none of them change it,

```
\renewcommand{\mspart}{Referencias}
```

Change the title to "ReferenciasReferences".

How can I change this title? (I am using BibTeX.)

Comment: Are you using Bibtex oder Biblatex?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Have you seen [How to change the name of document elements like “Figure”, “Contents”, “Bibliography” etc.?](http://goo.gl/CQdc6)

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The StackExchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Answer (score 3):

If you use `babel` you have to do nothing for changing the title:

```
%%% The filecontents* environment is only for making the example self-contained
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{x,
 author={X Y},
 title={Z},
 journal={J},
 year={1000},
}
\end{filecontents*}

%%% Here starts the document
\documentclass{apa6}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % recommended encoding
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\cite{x}

\bibliographystyle{apa}
\bibliography{\jobname} % use your bib file name

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What if one is not using `babel`, how can one change the "References" title. (We need to show it in all caps, yes, I know it is crazy).

Comment: @alfC `\renewcommand{\refname}{REFERENCES}` should do.

Comment: I mean in `apa6`, the question says such thing doesn't work with `apa6` (and I can confirm that).

Comment: @alfC If I replace `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` with `\renewcommand{\refname}{REFERENCES}` in the example above, I get ”REFERENCES“. If you use `babel`, then you should say `\addto{\captionsenglish}{\renewcommand{\refname}{REFERENCES}}` (with `english` replaced by the language you need).

Answer (score 2):

I know it is a very late answer, but maybe someone will find it helpful anyway.

This should work:

```
\renewcommand{\refname}{Referencias}
\printbibliography
```

For some reason when you renew the command in the preamble it does not work.

Comment: Thnks for the precision "for some reason when you renew the command in the preamble it does not work"!!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.

This is not a proper solution, but it worked for my purposes. Hope it will help in your case.

This chunk of code makes the Reference a separate section, which can be listed in Content. You can use `\section*{}` if you wish not to list it, of course.

```
\section{Referencias}
\renewcommand{\section}[2]{}
\printbibliography
```

Used the solution from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22654/51873

Comment: Why would you include `\normalfont` as part of your `\section`? That would, if successful, make its way into your ToC. And there's a difference in how `\section`s are formatted in the ToC compared to "other *normal font* components".

Comment: @Werner, I have got the wrong idea. It should be in bold, of course. I edited it.