# Remove a0 poster bibliography title

Tags: bibliographies, a0poster

I am creating a poster using the a0poster package. I want to remove the title of the bibliography which automatically comes up with 'References'.

All I have is this:

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{mybib}
```

I have seen this done for other packages but not sure how to do it for the a0 poster package.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate: You can find solution here --http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22654/34618