# Can't remove header from bibliography using BibTeX

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, header-footer

I can't remove the header of the bibliography. With this code, it deletes also the header of the previous chapter, which I wouldn't like to happen. Not using special packages such as `hyperref`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\pdfpagewidth
\paperwidth
\pdfpageheight
\paperheight
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{caption}
\geometry{a4paper,tmargin=3cm,bmargin=4cm, lmargin=3.7cm,rmargin=3.7cm} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{splitbib}

\begin{document}

Text,

previous chapter


\pagestyle{plain}
\sloppy

\begin{category}[]{Fonti delle figure}
  \SBentries{example}
\end{category}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\addtocounter{chapter}{1}
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}\bibname}
\bibliography{Bibname}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot   @naphaneal for the edit. Next time I'll do something better. Trying to get used using these codes. Of course I also forgot to put the \begin{document} command.

Comment: null sweat. you can edit your own posts by simply hitting the edit button.

Comment: But could you please help me? It's very urgent. I'd really appreciate that.

Comment: if you only want to remove the header of the bibliography use: `\renewcommand{\bibname}{}` where you put `\addcontentsline...`. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22645/hiding-the-title-of-the-bibliography for more information

Comment: I've just tried this way, but it shows an error.  "TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=10000]."

Comment: Do you mean you want no page headers, as produced by `fancyhdr` in the bibliography part? Then put the `\pagestyle{plain}` after the `\cleardoublepage`. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: It worked perfectly! Thanks a lot. Very kind.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for `\renewcommand\bibname{}`.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}%Silently cite all the entries in the bibliography file

\tableofcontents

\chapter{My First Chapter}
\lipsum[2-4]

\chapter{My Second Chapter}
\lipsum[2-4]

\bibliographystyle{plain}

\addtocounter{chapter}{1}

\renewcommand\bibname{My Custom Bibliography Name for TOC}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}\bibname}

%\renewcommand\bibname{Bibliography}
\renewcommand\bibname{}%leave blanc if you do not want to have the heading

%\bibliography{Bibname}
\begin{thebibliography}{10}
\bibitem{RefXX}
J.~Doe and J.~Black.
\newblock A review on something.
\newblock {\em Journal of Something}, 196(15):6007--6014, 2016.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This does not work: if one adds `\renewcommand\bibname{}', the header 'References' still shows up in the pdf