# References section in body of text

Tags: bibliographies

I'm writing up a proposal for my thesis and need to include the reference section as part of the overall paper (it's section 6 out of 7). The way I have it now I can get the references into that section of the proposal but it has a "References" heading that I can't seem to get rid of. I essentially just need to list the references in this section of the proposal by themselves.

At the head of the document:

```
\usepackage[super, sort]{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\bibliographystyle{plainurl}
```

In section 6 of the doc:

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{Proposal}
```

Is there a way to remove the "References" heading that I can't seem to get rid of?

Comment: You might find some helpful information here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22645/134144. Nevertheless, please turn your code fragments into a compilable [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407).