# Why is my bibliography a chapter?

Tags: bibliographies, chapters, report, tocbibind

I'm currently writing my thesis in latex and I'm using bibtex for my bibliography. The documentclass I'm using is 'report'.
I import my bibliography with the following commands:

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
```

`\bibliography{bibliography.bib}`

When I compile my text, the bibliography automatically compiles as a new chapter. I don't want it to be a chapter, does someone know how I can fix this?

I also use the following package: `\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}`.

Comment: Do you want your bibliography to be a `\section` or something else? Or do you simply want it to not start any sectioning level at all?

Comment: Not related to your question, but still something you should fix: The file name for `\bibliography` should *not* include the `.bib` file extension. The `\bibliography{bibliography.bib}` **should be `\bibliography{bibliography}`**. Some systems accept the incorrect input including `.bib`, but other systems are less forgiving. My MikTeX on Windows will throw an error on `\bibliography{bibliography.bib}`.

Comment: There you go: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22645/hiding-the-title-of-the-bibliography

Comment: You ask, "why is my bibliography a chapter?" Answer: Because you're using the `report` document class.