# How can Bib(La)TeX usage be refactored for compatibility with ScholarOne's manuscript submission system

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, natbib, journal-publishing

I was recently asked how I had previously refactored my LaTeX code, to allow the ScholarOne manuscript submission system to properly accept conventional Bib(La)TeX usage.

I briefly outline the main steps I took, in my accompanying answer.

Please note that their system has since improved, so it is likely that some of these steps are no longer necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While a number of additional refactoring steps used to be needed, within the ScholarOne interface (such as moving specific portions of `sty` files to within the "main document"), I believe this is no longer necessary.

Mainly, the key is to load the `bib` and `sty` files from the (system-designated) "main file" (e.g. `document.tex`), to obviate errors during submission. Specifically, this triggers the system's dependency detection, which appears necessary for valid compilation.

The preamble of the main document remains as usual. Assuming one is using `natbib` (loaded from the class file) and has a Bib(La)TeX file, `referenes.bib`:

```
\bibinput{references} % this still does not trigger dependency detection in system; need to manually do so
\bibliographystyle{XXX-natbib}  % where XXX indicates your journal-specific name
```

The following should then be substituted, at the end of `doucument.tex`, instead of the usual simpler bibliographic command(s):

```
\IfFileExists{./document.bbl}{
  \input{document.bbl}
  %
  % manually balance the columns on the final page by increasing right column, due to phantom bibliography preventing automatic balancing
  \atColsEnd{\vskip-455pt}
  % force dependency detection within the submission system to find "references.bib", s.t. usebib can find it
  \suppress%
  \begingroup%
  % do not create another section; from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22654
  \renewcommand{\section}[2]{}%
  \bibliography{references}
  \endgroup%
  \endsuppress%
}{
  \bibliography{references}
}
```

---

This may not work directly.  One workaround is to instead generate the `bbl` file oneself, and upload that to the ScholarOne system, including it manually.