# Delete the word ``reference'' in a block

Tags: spacing, bibliographies, block, tikzposter

```
\documentclass{tikzposter} %Options for format can be included here

 % Title, Author, Institute
\title{Template Poster}
\author{Author(s)}
\institute{Institute}
\titlegraphic{LogoGraphic Inserted Here}

 %Choose Layout
\usetheme{Default}

\begin{document}

 % Title block with title, author, logo, etc.
\maketitle
 \block{Basic Block}{Text}
 \begin{columns}

 % FIRST column
\column{0.6}% Width set relative to text width

\block{Large Column}{In \cite{ss} we have...and in \cite{ss2} we also have...........\\Text\\Text Text Text}
\note{Note with default behavior}
\note[targetoffsetx=12cm, targetoffsety=-1cm, angle=20, rotate=25]
{Note \\ offset and rotated}

 % First column - second block
\block{Block titles with enough text will automatically obey spacing requirements }
{Text\\Text}

 % First column - third block
\block{Sample Block 4}{T\\E\\S\\T}

 % SECOND column
\column{0.4}
 %Second column with first block's top edge aligned with with previous column's top.

 % Second column - first block
\block[titleleft]{Smaller Column}{Test}

 % Second column - second block
\block[titlewidthscale=0.6, bodywidthscale=0.8]
{Variable width title}{Block with smaller width.}

 % Second column - third block
\block{}{Block with no title}

 % Second column - A collection of blocks in subcolumn environment.
\begin{subcolumns}
    \subcolumn{0.27} \block{1}{First block.} \block{2}{Second block}
    \subcolumn{0.4} \block{Sub-columns}{Sample subblocks\\Second subcolumn}
    \subcolumn{0.33} \block{4}{Fourth} \block{}{Final Subcolumn block}
\end{subcolumns}

 % Bottomblock
\block{Final Block in column}{
    Sample block.
}
\end{columns}


\block[titlewidthscale=0.6, bodywidthscale=0.9]
{References}{
\begin{thebibliography}{10}
\bibitem{ss} Sever S Dragomir, Inequalities for the numerical radius of linear operators in Hilbert spaces, Springer, 2013.
\bibitem{ss2} Karl E Gustafson and Duggirala KM Rao, Numerical range,  Springer, 1997.
\end{thebibliography}
}

\end{document}



\endinput
%%
%% End of file `tikzposter-template.tex'.
```

> I want to delete the word references and the extra spaces

[image]

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22654/36296

Comment: Dear  @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I hope you can help me in my situation since it does not work to me. Thanks in advance

Comment: I posted an answer, but it is really just copy&paste from the answer I linked to above...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the same approach as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22654/36296

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}

\usetheme{Default}

\begin{document}

\block[titlewidthscale=0.6, bodywidthscale=0.9]
{References}{
\renewcommand{\section}[2]{}%
\begin{thebibliography}{10}
\bibitem{ss} Sever S Dragomir, Inequalities for the numerical radius of linear operators in Hilbert spaces, Springer, 2013.
\bibitem{ss2} Karl E Gustafson and Duggirala KM Rao, Numerical range,  Springer, 1997.
\end{thebibliography}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]